# Why should we set Scope to 'Web Application' in Timer Job?

Tags: timer-jobs, sandbox-solution, web-application, farm-solution, feature-scope

Though we are activating feature from web application still web(sub site) or site collection comes under the Web Application scope , what is specific reason to select scope as "Web Application"
Thanks.

Comment: may be  the timerjob is listed in the central admin's timer job definitions page / module such that it needs to be in web appln level scope. also  the timer service Caches the assembly with your class. Also all SP Timer jobs have a scope of action – an object type upon which they are intended to work. This scope may be the farm, an individual server, or a content database. That is, for each iteration of a job, it is expected to execute once per farm, once per server, or once per content database